# Time series from a given autocorrelation

Tags: time-series, simulation, autocorrelation

I am trying to generate a time series for $r(t)$ given the following autocorrelation function

$$
 \langle r(0) r(\tau)\rangle 
     =
     \int_{\Omega_\mathrm{min}}^{\Omega_\mathrm{max}}dz 
     \coth\left(\frac{z}{2\Omega_T}\right)
     \frac{\cos\left(\tau z\right)}{\sqrt{z^2 - \Omega^2_\mathrm{min}}\sqrt{\Omega^2_\mathrm{max} - z^2 }}
$$
and zero mean.

This function describes the motion of one of the masses in an infinite 1D harmonic chain with the minimum mode frequency $\Omega_\mathrm{min}$ and the maximum one $\Omega_\mathrm{max}$ at temperature $k_BT = \hbar \Omega_T$.

I tried generating the time series using both the Cholesky approach, as well as generating one step at a time using the marginal probability. I tried to speed up the latter using the Levinson-Durbin formula. The issue, however, is not the speed.

If the time steps used are smaller than $2\pi / \Omega_\mathrm{max}$, within a few time steps, the covariance matrix $\Sigma$ acquires negative eigenvalues with all the associated problems. While I do expect zero eigenvalues because of the mutual dependence of prior $r$'s, the negative ones were a little surprising, especially that they weren't *that* small: $\sim -10^{-8}$. The resources online typically address the issue of low-rank $\Sigma$, but the rank here appear to be appropriate when I check it numerically.

The physical problem is, in principle, solvable by simulating a large number of individual oscillators with amplitudes drawn from the appropriate distribution. I was hoping, however, to be able to use the explicit autocorrelation expression instead.

Comment: _Many_ different time series can have the same autocorrelation function, and so whatever answer your simulation/generation procedure might produce is just one of many possible valid results.

Comment: Thank you for being willing to help! Right, that makes sense: different runs will give different results. The issue that's bothering me is that the result is not valid because of the negative eigenvalues. Time-locally, it looks OK, but if I cannot use Yule-Walker (because I get a negative variance), then how robust are these results? If I only can use a few prior steps, I cannot guarantee the correct autocorrelation value for more than that time segment